# What is "Interrupt Context Saving" in embedded systems?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, mikroc

What is "Interrupt Context Saving" in embedded systems? I am configuring interrupt handlers in an IDE that I am new to. In the configuration setup it gives me the option of no context saving or "Auto" (Compiler chooses whether the context saving will be perfomed or not). Which should I choose and why?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic context saving means that the device will, upon an interrupt request, save basic registers (In a PIC > W, STATUS, BSR, FSR, PCLATH, etc) to shadow registers.

When returning from the interrupt routine, these registers are automatically restored to the values they had before the ISR.

Using it rely on your firmware.